# How to get the # of ether or any other token only by knowing their decimals

Tags: solidity

How do I convert 2060881467756432366 into Ether which has 18 decimals.

More specifically I need to be able to do this for multiple tokens and I know how many they have plus how many decimal points the token has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from a Big Number -> Float can be done manually like so:

```
places = 18
integer = 10**places
number = 2060881467756432366 
decimal = number / integer
print(decimal)
```

or by using `web3`

`w3.fromWei(2060881467756432366 , "ether")`

the same works inversely with `toWei()`

To get the number of decimals can be obtained from the contracts `decimals` function  in that contract.

if you do not have the `abi` this is standard in ERC20 contracts so you can use any ERC20 ABI.

`decimals` is NOT required for an ERC20 token but it is recommended and will most likely exist.

```
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract, abi=abi)
contract.functions.decimals().call()
>>> 18
```

Comment: Was able to make a function with the manual code example. Thank you!
  function fromBigNumber(bigNumber, decimals) {
    let integer = 10 ** decimals;
    let workableNumber = bigNumber / integer;
    return workableNumber;
  }
  console.log(fromBigNumber(2060881467756432366, 18));

--> 2.06.... as it should be.

Comment: That looks correct as well but please be aware that `fromWei` is a web3 method and is also available in JS if you need :)

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#fromwei